# Definition of differentiability of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

One definition I found is the following.

> **Defferentiability** The function $z=f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ provided $f_x(a,b)$ and $f_y(a,b)$ exist and $$\Delta z:=f(a+\Delta x,b+\Delta y)-f(a,b)=f_x(a,b)\Delta x+f_y(a,b)\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y$$,
> where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are changes in $x$ and $y$ repectively, and $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are functions that depend only on $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ respectively, with $(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)\to(0,0)$ as $(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)$.

It is known that $f(x,y)=1-|xy|$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and

- $\Delta z=-|\Delta x\Delta y|$
- $f_x(a,b)\Delta x+f_y(a,b)\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y=\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y$.

But I don't think there are functions $\epsilon_1$ of $\Delta x$ and $\epsilon_2$ of $\Delta y$ satisfying
$$-|\Delta x\Delta y|=\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon\Delta y$$ with the above conditions.

I was wondering if I am wrong or the defition above is incorrect.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, $1-|xy|$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\epsilon_1 = -\frac{\Delta x (\Delta y)^2}{2|\Delta x \Delta y|}$ and $\epsilon_2 = -\frac{\Delta y (\Delta x)^2}{2|\Delta x \Delta y|}$ will do it as you can easily check.

Comment: Then would $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ be functions of both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$?

Comment: @JunpyoChoi Yes, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ depend on $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$. Otherwise your definition of differentiability is not equivalent to the usual one.